# Initializing private member in constructor

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to make an attiny flicker an LED simulating a candle.  I know very very little about C++.

I have a class called `CandleAnimation` that is constructed with a reference to an object that controls the LED.  I'd like to construct a `Candle` object that maintains the state of the simulated candle.

The run loop calls an `animate` method on the `CandleAnimation`.  I'm not positive what exactly is going on here, but it seems like my `Candle` is going out of scope and is getting destroyed.

```
#include "candle_animation.h"

CandleAnimation::CandleAnimation(Led *led, Color flameColor) {
  _led = led;

  Candle candle(_led, 0xFF0000);
  _candle = &candle;

  _candle->play(); // shows red as expected
  delay(500); // this prevents the run loop from starting so I have to delete this code to get the animate to work
}

void CandleAnimation::animate(int sliderValue, int ambientBrightness) {
  Candle otherCandle(_led, 0x00FF00);
  otherCandle.play(); // shows green as expected

  delay(500); // this stops the following code from being random actually.  instead it's a dim green on the LED

  _candle->play(); // shows grazy things . . . seemingly random
}
```

So, how do I initialize my instance with a pointer to an object and keep that object around so that I can use it in other member methods?

Comment: Why are you storing a pointer to a `Candle` in `CandleAnimation` instead of just holding on to a `Candle` itself?

Comment: Change the member to `std::unique_ptr<Candle>` and use `_candle = std::make_unique<Candle>(_led, 0xFF0000);`

Comment: `_candle = new Candle(_led, 0xFF0000);`

Comment: @NathanOliver, primarily because I didn't want to have a default constructor that yielded an invalid instance.  Is that dumb?  I did the same thing with the LED class.  Basically, an LED instance can't do anything without having a value for the red, green, and blue pins.  So, I couldn't just say `Led led`.  Same with Candle.  It's not valid without an Led instance or a Color.  I'm open to alternatives for sure because I'd prefer to pass the instance around instead.

Comment: @D.Patrick Then don't provide a default constructor.  If it's not usable until you know what you want to use, just hold off on declaring it until you know what you want.

Comment: Heh, wait . . . I can do that?  So, did I mention I'm very very new to C++?  So far everyone's like, "declare all your variables in the header . . ."  How do I hold off on declaring it until I know what I want?

Comment: Your observation that `candle` goes out of scope is indeed correct. The "[c]razy things" you are observing are [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  Lets say you need to wait for the pin and color.  you would do something like `pin_type pin; color_type color; get_pin(); get_color(); animation a(pin, color)`.  A good guideline is to declare variables as close to the point of use as possible.

Comment: @super, that works like a charm . . . I gotta figure out why. :) Oh, hey.  Because C++ does that.  When I do `Candle(led, 0xFF)` that's getting deallocated when the scope exits.  The new operator is allocating the memory elsewhere.  Would I typically also need to delete it somewhere?  The destructor perhaps?  Thanks!

Comment: @D.Patrick Yes, you need to `delete` it at some point. When it's no longer needed. But if the lifetime of your `Candle` is tied to the lifetime of your `CandleAnimation` then maybe you could store a `Candle` instead of a `Candle*` in it.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks.  I do indeed.  :)  I'm not used to not having null, undefined, nil, etc.  I'm used to declaring a reference variable and assigning it later so that the instance can have internal state.  That's why I tried to declare it in the header.  If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying, maybe don't try to create the candle in the constructor.  Rather pass the details I have to the constructor and build the candle each run loop?  Or, build the candle where the pins are available and pass it to the constructor instead?  I'd still need to declare it in the .h then right?

Comment: @D.Patrick Kind of.  It really depends on how you are using it.  I envision something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d77abf5950465ac) but that's just one way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep a proper candle object in your class, use this in the header:

```
Led* _led;
Candle _candle;
```

In which case the constructor becomes:

```
CandleAnimation::CandleAnimation(Led *led, Color flameColor)
: _led(led)
, _candle(led, 0xFF0000)
{
   // Rest of the constructor
}
```

If you want to keep with dynamic allocation (you don't), declare `_candle` as a `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Candle > _candle ;
```

And then (if you have C++14):

```
_candle  = std::make_unique(_led, 0xFF0000);
```

In C++11:

```
_candle  = std::unique_ptr(new Candle(_led, 0xFF0000));
```

If you don't have modern C++ (not sure what arduino offers?), you need to do the same, but keep track on the `_candle` lifetime.

Comment: @NathanOliver indeed, everything OP wants can be done in the initialization list.

Comment: OK.  This is really good.  I like the initializer list approach quite a bit.  Thanks very much for your time.  I'd like to do the same thing with _led too.  _led is declared as a protected member on an inherited class (I'm calling it an abstract class).  I can't put _led in the initializer list for CandleAnimation.  Should I ask how to do that as a separate question?

Comment: I can answer this here. As long as you pass `led` to the parent constructor (so the abstract class needs a constructor), when `_candle` gets initialized, `_led` already will be. You can use it safely then.

Comment: Mmm.  I can call the base class constructor in the initialization list.  Dude, this is so clean!  I love it.  Thank you very much. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
CandleAnimation::CandleAnimation(Led *led, Color flameColor)
    : _candle(new Candle(led, 0xFF0000)) // this is making you sure that your candle will be valid until being deleted
{
  _led = led;

  //  Candle candle(_led, 0xFF0000); this is a local variable and will be deleted after constructor execution. You don't need it anymore
  //  _candle = &candle;

  _candle->play(); // shows red as expected
  delay(500); // this prevents the run loop from starting so I have to delete this code to get the animate to work
}
// don't forget to delete _candle in destructor
```

Comment: I've just fixed code regarding _candle problem. In your answer there is problem. _candle as I can see in code is pointer, but you have initialized it as an member. Also in arduino there is no stl included. so std:: namespace is inaccessible.

Comment: That's why I added the change in the header.

Comment: I decided, that he already have declared those variables in class.

Comment: @ArsenGharagyozyan That's not the problem.  When you do `_candle(new Candle(_led, 0xFF0000))`.  What is the value of `_led`?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher A better word would be initialized.  It is defined, just not initialized.

Comment: Yep I fixed it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I shouldn't have had the day I had :p